# Why can't I use pointers with a ternary operator?

Tags: c, lvalue

Task: int's and pointers to them are given. Using only pointers, find the variable with the minimum value among the variables and assign the minimum to the maximum.
Question: Why does the code below output "the value required as the left assignment operand"
*p_a < *p_b ? *p_b = *p_a : *p_a = *p_b;

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { 
    int a = 5, b = 7;
    int * p_a = &a, *p_b = &b;
    *p_a < *p_b ? *p_b = *p_a : *p_a = *p_b;
    printf("%d %d", *p_a, *p_b);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to enter a flag that will take on the minimum number, but it also didn't work
Example of a flag

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { 
    int a = 5, b = 7;
    int * p_a = &a, *p_b = &b;
    int l; //flag
    *p_a < *p_b ? l = *p_a : l = *p_b;
    printf("%d", l);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are using ternary as though it is if-then, and ignoring precedence.

Comment: Try `*p_a = *p_b = *p_a < *p_b ? *p_a : *p_b;` . This is a bit wasteful, assigning one of the values to itself, but it fits on one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add parentheses to group the assignments.  For example:

```
int main() { 
    int a = 5, b = 7;
    int * p_a = &a, *p_b = &b;
    *p_a < *p_b ? (*p_b = *p_a) : (*p_a = *p_b);
    printf("%d %d", *p_a, *p_b);
    return 0;
}
```

and

```
int main() { 
    int a = 5, b = 7;
    int * p_a = &a, *p_b = &b;
    int l; //flag
    *p_a < *p_b ? (l = *p_a) : (l = *p_b);
    printf("%d", l);
    return 0;
}
```

It is a bit strange to use `?:` like this though.  Normally you would use the ternary operator when you actually want to use its value.  In a case like this, where you're just performing assignments and not using the result value of the operator, you would normally use `if`/`else`.

Comment: I'm just learning. I was thinking how to shorten the solution, I didn't want to use if else. I am grateful to you for the answer, it helped me a lot!

Comment: @kikjoan, unless you're playing code golf, minimum source code length is not a very good coding objective.  Aim instead for *clear* and *simple* code.  Often the shortest possible source is more difficult to read or reason about than various somewhat longer sources.

Comment: @kikjoan - There is no additional "cost per line" for C code. Writing one complicated line of code instead of four simple ones (if-else) has no advantage at all. It only makes the code harder to understand.